# how can pass data From URL to web Api controller for testing in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api2

This is my ApiController Code.

```
 // POST: api/SecurityApi
    [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostUser([FromUri] GeneralViewModel model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User _user = new User();
            _user.FullName = model.Security.FullName;
            _user.Email = model.Security.Email;
            _user.PhoneNo = model.Security.MobileNumber;
            _user.Password = model.Security.Password;
            _user.RetypePassword = model.Security.RetypePassword;
            _user.CityId = model.Security.CityId;
            _user.IsUpdate = model.Security.IsUpdate;
            _user.StatusId = (byte)Utilities.Status.Active;
            _user.EmailConfirmed = false;
            _user.Image = "/images/business.png";
            _user.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            _user.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            _user.CreatedBy = 1;
            var userObj = seuritybll.Insert(_user);
            //configur Email
            EmailModel _m = new EmailModel();
            _m.toAddress.Add(model.Security.Email);
            _m.Url = "http://www.bedspacefinders.com/Security/CompleteRegistration/" + userObj.ID;
            _m.Subject = "Registration Email";
            _m.Body = "To complete registration " + "<a href='" + _m.Url + "'>click here.</a> ";
            Utilities.Utilities.SendEmail(_m);
            return Ok(true);

        }
        else
        {
            return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }
        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = user.ID }, user);
    }
```

this is my url "http://localhost:12865/api/SecurityApi" for api now i want to pass data from url to Model for UserRegistration But i dont know how pass data from url to apiController first i used http://localhost:12865/api/SecurityApi?"{firstName:"aitzaz"}"; but not working any one can help me how i can pass data from url to apiModel

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Form format to pass the model

it will be

```
http://localhost:12865/api/SecurityApi?firstName=aitzaz
```

if you have multiple properties for the model

it should be

```
http://localhost:12865/api/SecurityApi?firstName=aitzaz&somethingElse=xxxx
```

Comment: I used ViewModel for single model its working fine but for ViewModel it's not working because i have ViewModel.

Comment: pretty confusing, i don't understand what do you mean